# Where is the data of this struct located in memory?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, stl

I am looking at the GCC source code of std::set in stl_tree.h and there is this:

```
  enum _Rb_tree_color { _S_red = false, _S_black = true };

  struct _Rb_tree_node_base
  {
    typedef _Rb_tree_node_base* _Base_ptr;
    typedef const _Rb_tree_node_base* _Const_Base_ptr;

    _Rb_tree_color  _M_color;
    _Base_ptr       _M_parent;
    _Base_ptr       _M_left;
    _Base_ptr       _M_right;

    static _Base_ptr
    _S_minimum(_Base_ptr __x)
    {
      while (__x->_M_left != 0) __x = __x->_M_left;
      return __x;
    }

    static _Const_Base_ptr
    _S_minimum(_Const_Base_ptr __x)
    {
      while (__x->_M_left != 0) __x = __x->_M_left;
      return __x;
    }

    static _Base_ptr
    _S_maximum(_Base_ptr __x)
    {
      while (__x->_M_right != 0) __x = __x->_M_right;
      return __x;
    }

    static _Const_Base_ptr
    _S_maximum(_Const_Base_ptr __x)
    {
      while (__x->_M_right != 0) __x = __x->_M_right;
      return __x;
    }
  };
```

The three pointer data members:

```
    _Base_ptr       _M_parent;
    _Base_ptr       _M_left;
    _Base_ptr       _M_right;
```

assuming the default allocator, **would the data pointed to by these pointers be randomly allocated on the heap?**

UPDATE:

@Jeff I am trying to figure out, looking at this code:

```
struct _Rb_tree_impl : public _Node_allocator
        {
      _Key_compare      _M_key_compare;
      _Rb_tree_node_base    _M_header;
      size_type         _M_node_count; // Keeps track of size of tree.
           .
           .
           .
```

**Would `_M_node_count` and `_M_header._M_left` be in separate cache lines?** They are referenced here:

```
const_iterator begin() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
{ 
   return const_iterator(static_cast<_Const_Link_type>(this->_M_impl._M_header._M_left));
}

  size_type size() const _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT 
  { 
      return _M_impl._M_node_count; 
  }
```

Comment: `libstdc++` nowadays will try to use block allocators that set aside arrays of smaller, fixed-sized entities. If you're not doing too much else, there is a very high chance that a reasonable number of nodes can be allocated contiguously in the free store in order of their creation. Unless you insert values in a structured order (i.e., final in-order or level-order), the pattern of parent/left/right pointers may still seem pretty random, though. What are you trying to solve or figure out?

Comment: @Jeff I'll post an UPDATE to show you what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @Jeff ok have updated Q.

Comment: `_Rb_tree::_Rb_tree_impl::_M_node_count` and `_Rb_tree_node_base::_M_header._M_left` (the pointer) have a very high, nearly guaranteed chance of being in the same cache line if I'm reading `bits/stl_tree.h` right. The node that `_M_left` points to will have a nearly 0% chance of being on the same cache line, unless you're doing a 32 bit compile on a `std::set<char>`, and maybe not even then. Cache lines are just too small (64B typically)

Comment: @Jeff just to clarify, the data pointed to by "this->_M_impl._M_header._M_left" has a 0% chance of being in the same cache line as _M_node_count? Not that I doubt you- but could you explain why exactly? (just want to learn)

Comment: Sure. For a `set` or `map`, the value (and optionally key) are stored in a node, which has an underlying overhead equivalent of about 5 or 6 pointers/counters, including padding. This is >=20B on 32b platforms, NOT including any payload, and >=40B on 64b, out of a total 64B cache line size on most platforms. So at most one other node might share the cache line on some platforms for small `set<T>` `T`s, and it's not highly likely for large `set`/`map`s that a left/right/parent node was the previous/next node created unless you carefully order your `insert()` calls.

Comment: Ah so what you're saying is _M_header._M_left and (possibly, but unlikely) _M_header._M_right share the same cache line- but because each of these is going to be at least 40 bytes (on 64 bit) that will be 80 bytes and therefore the size member will be in a different cache line?

Comment: Jeff, got one more tiny related Q. rbegin() calls end() and end() has return const_iterator(static_cast<_Const_Link_type> (&this->_M_impl._M_header)); Now _M_impl._M_header is a _Rb_tree_node_base object member of _Rb_tree_impl. Would this access a different cache line to _M_node_count? I am guessing not because it doesn't seem to dereference the pointer, just take the address (and ._M_header is located next to _M_node_count?

Comment: Of course `_M_header._M_left` and `_M_header._M_right` share the same cache line - they're adjacent.  The data they point at is an entirely different story, though.  And `end()` probably doesn't even access the memory `this` points at, just the `this` address itself, which is presumably on the stack as a function argument.

Comment: The layout of an RBT node is roughly this: `struct N { T; int; N *p, *l, *r; int; };` which is nearly a cache line in size in the best of cases. For small `T`s, a node (plus *maybe*) part of another partial node can fit in a line. The nodes that `p/l/r` point to have a small, probabilistic chance of being that *other* partial node, but you can probably expect that to *not* be the case. Like aschepler says, it's highly probably that the pointers are in the same cache line, ~15/16ths chance on 32b if `alignof(T) <= 4` and 7/8ths on 64b if `alignof(T) <= 8`.

Comment: @aschepler Apologies- werent sure if I read your comment correctly. You are saying end(), which calls "return const_iterator(static_cast<_Const_Link_type> (&this->_M_impl._M_header));" so it takes the address of _M_impl._M_header WOULDNT access the same cache line as _M_impl._M_node_count? But _M_impl._M_header and _M_impl._M_node_count are located next to each other in the _Rb_tree_impl struct?

Comment: Ah got it- I was thinking _M_impl._M_header was a pointer! But its not right, its an object? Hence Jeff is saying how large the typical node will be and therefore _M_impl._M_node_count will be in a different cache line. Sorry- was thinking it was a pointer!!!

Comment: I'm saying taking the address `&this->_M_impl._M_header` doesn't access any cache line at all, assuming the `this` pointer is already in a register.  It's just pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @aschepler ok but the pointer arithmetic must lead to some memory being accessed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The g++ library actually uses that `_Rb_tree_node_base` type for two different purposes:

1. The nodes of the red-black tree.  One object of a type derived from `_Rb_tree_node_base` is allocated on the heap for each element in the container.

   a. `_M_color` is an enum declaring the node red or black for red-black tree algorithms.

   b. `_M_parent` points at the parent node, or if the node is the root, points at the tree's "header" (see below).

   c. `_M_left` points at the left child node, or null if there is none.

   d. `_M_right` points at the right child node, or null if there is none.

   e. Another member in the derived class contains the actual container element.
2. The "header", which is the subobject `_M_header` inside the actual container object.

   a. `_M_color` is always red (which helps some iterator algorithms).

   b. `_M_parent` points at the root node, or is null if the container is empty.

   c. `_M_left` points at the first node in sort order, or at the header itself if the container is empty.

   d. `_M_right` points at the last node in sort order, or at the header itself if the container is empty.

An iterator which is "past-the-end" also points at the container's header.

So to (almost) answer your question, `c._M_node_count` and `c._M_header._M_left` are both subobjects of `c`.  But if `c` is not empty, the data pointed to by `c._M_header._M_left` is outside of `c` and was allocated by `c`'s allocator.